# Extra Height Generated in Firefox for my Website

Tags: html, css, firefox

Firefox is generating some extra 250px in the end of my website beneath the footer, I have not yet found a reason why this is happening.

PS. It runs fine on the others browsers, the problem is just with firefox.

The site I am working on is http://www.ryansammut.com/orijen/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validate your code using the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

You have loads of errors - once you have fixed these you will probably find that your site works as expected. If not, then give another shout and we'll investigate it further.

---- Edit ----

The problem was that you were using position: absolute with a negative margin of -220px on one of your lines. As this was nested within multiple divs I guess it confused the browser.

You can use the following to fix the issue:

add

```
float: left;
```

to the divs #line1 and #line 2. And do not forget to clear your divs after by using

```
clear: both;
```

You will also have to repostion the top position of your line.

If you need anymore help or this does not fix your issue then pleae just post a comment below.

Comment: Yes I will fix them, however most of the errors are genereated because of Dreamweaver's Rollover Script

Comment: @My Head Hurts - I fixed the relevant errors, the other errors are generated by dreamweaver, or from other scripts. I still did not fix the footer problem, and the css is valid.

Comment: @Ryan Sammut - The most concerning error I see (that isn't script related) is -> "Line 315, Column 7: end tag for "body" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified". Which IDE do you use write your code? - a good one will help you spot nesting errors.

Comment: @My Head Hurts - I use dreamweaver, and that's not really ommitted, it is because I am using <body onload="...."> to import the images for the rollovers on load.

Comment: @Ryan Summit - In that case the problem is with your footer. I have ammended my answer with a fix.

Comment: @My Head Hurts - is this what you meant? because it did not fix it

#line1
{
 position: relative;
 width: 10px;
 left: 530px;
 top: -40px;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
}

Comment: I fixed it just by putting the second line as margin-top instead of top

Comment: @Ryan Summit - I am glad you managed to fix it. Just to answer your other comment, clear: both would not have gone in the #line1 id. You would need to have made a new class and then added this as a new div or li after #line2. For example   <css>.clear{ clear: both} </css> and <html> <li id="1">...</li><li id="2">...</li><li class="clear">&nbsp</li> </html>

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a style block that is occurring inside the body of your code.  That might be resulting in Firefox not closing out the body correctly.  You have a bunch more validation errors you might want to clean up.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ryansammut.com%2Forijen%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

**UPDATE:**

It looks like your #line1 and #line2 list items in the #footerItems need to be given a position: absolute.  You'll have to adjust your positioning of those elements, but that should fix the issue in firefox.

Comment: I fixed the needed errors in my site, the others are generated from Dreamweaver or other scripts I am using.